# Scheduled tasks for GPIO Raspberry Pi on PHP?

Tags: php, web-interface

I create a web interface for me for manager raspberry pi gpio.
Are there libraries for PHP for scheduled tasks for GPIO Raspberry Pi?

I want add task from web interface, for example "at 9:00 set value for some 20 GPIO pin everyday". This is possible?

Thank you advance

Comment: How to "*set value for some 20 GPIO*"? If it's a command, add to the question.

Comment: Ah, just now I googled but only found PHP GPIO libraries not up to date, or based on wiring pi which has depreciated. An example is:  https://www.xodustech.com/guides/raspberry-pi-php-gpio.  Can you let us know which PHP GPIO library you are using now, and which php cron?